# Unity искажает текстуру?

Tags: unity3d, photoshop, blender

Я сделал текстуру низкого разрешения для своей 3D модели (в photoshop). В Blender текстура на модели выглядит отлично, но когда я импортирую её в Unity, она теряет детали, даже когда выставлен point filter:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель из blender, я импортировал в unity в формате FBX.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может в unity не хватает галочки `Alpha is transparency`

Comment: Кроме фильтра, установи компрессию с биллинейной на `None`.

Comment: И то, и то сделал, получилось вот так. (добавил картинку в вопрос). Пробовал изменять Tiling и offset - не помогает.